# Scrapy get data through json tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import HomedepotItem
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



class HomedepotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'homeDepot'


    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560']
     


    def parse(self, response):


        for item in self.parseHomeDepot(response):
            yield item
        pass

    def parseHomeDepot(self, response):
        item = HomedepotItem() #items from items.py


        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text)
        productPrice = jsonresponse(["offers"][0]["price"])
        

     
        #item['productPrice'] = productPrice #display price and assign to variable
   

        yield item
```

I'm trying to parse data from the json of this webpage. I had a previous question answered regarding the json and ["offers"]["prices"] was the way to go since the json of the webpage is

```
"offers":{"@type":"Offer","url":"https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560","priceCurrency":"USD","price":1449.95,"priceValidUntil":"4/7/2021","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock"}
```

so now I get the error: r`aise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are getting the error because you are trying to do `json.loads` on the entire webpage, not just the json component

Comment: @tomjn so I would load the offers object in my json response 
then loop through it to try and get the price?

Comment: @TowsifAhamedLabib I dont think I can use response.css since the content is generated dynamically

Comment: since you mentioned a previous question I looked at that and that has the answer to your question in. What am I missing here? You can use `response.css` to load the `json` similar to what is done in the answer to your previous question...

Comment: @tomjn I did try that but I may have loaded it in incorrectly, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because you cannot just simply grab the `JSON` that's in a `<script>` tag with just pure `response.text`.

The `JSON` you want is in the first `script` tag of `type` `application/ld+json`.

You have to target that specific tag and *then* parse it with `json.loads`.

For example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

import scrapy


class HomedepotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'homeDepot'
    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560']

    def parse(self, response):
        script_tag = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"][1]/text()').get()
        yield json.loads(script_tag)
```

Here's a sample from `scrapy shell`:

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560'
...

[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f2d56604160>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560>
[s]   response   <200 https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f2d56680ac0>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x7f2d56105850>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects 
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>> script_tag = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"][1]/text()').get()
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(script_tag)["offers"]
{'@type': 'Offer', 'url': 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560', 'priceCurrency': 'USD', 'price': 1449.95, 'priceValidUntil': '4/12/2021', 'availability': 'https://schema.org/InStock'}
>>> json.loads(script_tag)["offers"]["price"]
1449.95
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, is //script[@type="application/ld+json" standard for scraping json elements from a webpage or does that vary based on website?

Comment: @chrisHG the answer is - it depends. However, `application/ld+json` is a relatively common type for the `<script>` that carries some payload that's consumed usually by `JavaScript`.

Comment: gotcha i ctrl+f'd the page source and now know what to look for. Thanks for all your help, I learned a ton from your answer!

Comment: Glad to help out! Happy coding and scraping! :)